# JavaFX : Button never sets a graphic

Tags: java, javafx, controller

### EDIT :

A MCVE version of my code has been made to help debug it. It reproduces my bug. The purpose of my code is doing a Memory game. Which means that when it is your turn, you "open" a card, then another one. If they form a pair, they don't get turned over, they stay open. Otherwise, you turn them back over and try to find a pair on the next turn.

Simply put, the bug is : when you are opening the second card of your turn and both cards don't form a pair, the second one never gets opened!

Hopefully, this version of my code will help you to find the bug, which will help me a lot!

I have put the code on Github : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e866671d80384ae53b53
(And you will find it *attached* at the end of the question)

---

### Explanation of the issue

I am having fun on doing a little Memory game in JavaFX and I came across this strange behavior where the card I click on (represented by a custom class that extends the Button class) never changes the image displayed.

Normally, when I click on the card, it "opens" itself by changing the graphic it displays.
The strange and annoying thing is that it only happens in a specific case.

The behavior of my card is correct when I "open" the first card of the turn of the player. It also works when I "open" a second one and both cards are a pair. Sadly, it doesn't work only in the case where I want to open a second card and it doesn't match as a pair with the first one.

I modified the Button class by adding `openCard()` and `closeCard()` methods. Those methods will set a specific graphic on the button-card.

I will now show some code but it is hard to tell what might be the part that is making this behavior happen. Even more so that I am using Eclipse but can't possibly figure out how to debug a JavaFX app with breakpoints (I am using console prints) because the app will eventually crash when I reach my breakpoints and start crawling through the lines of code.

---

### The code

Firstly, the modified Button class :

```
public class Card extends Button{
private String cardDesign;

public Card(int row, int column){
  this.setGraphic(new ImageView("/resources/card_back.png"));
  this.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.SLATEGRAY,
      new CornerRadii(6), null)));
}

public void setOpenCardDesign(String design){ cardDesign = design; }

public void openCard(){ this.setGraphic(new ImageView(cardDesign)); }

public void closeCard(){
  this.setGraphic(new ImageView("/resources/card_back.png"));
}
```

}

Now the controller class, the event is set on a `MouseEvent`. There is more code in this controller (like checking if there is a pair), but this isn't an issue here I think as the problem is already at the line where I call the method to open the card.
I use the  `getSource()` method here because my cards are arranged in a gridPane and I need to know which one has been clicked on.

```
@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
  //Get the card that was clicked on
  Card card = (Card) event.getSource();
  //Open the card
  card.openCard();
  //Do some more after this...
```

}

---

That's pretty much it as from what I could figure out.

As already stated, I tried to check if the method `openCard()` is being called. It is as some comment printed in my console showed up. I even added some console printing just before and just after the line where I set the graphic and they both are showing up. I can't know for sure what happens when my app reaches the `setGraphic()` line as nothing is showing up in my app (the card remains closed).

Any hint would help because I am slowly sinking in madness right now.
Thank you in advance.

---

### The MCVE version of my code

**The card object** : `Card.java`

```
package memory;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Card extends Button{
//-------------------------------------------------
  //Store the position of the card
  private int row;
  private int column;
//-------------------------------------------------
  //Constructor
  public Card(int row, int column){
    //Give the cards a specific color at init
    this.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.DEEPSKYBLUE,
        new CornerRadii(6), null)));
    this.setText("CLOSED");
    this.row = row;
    this.column = column;
  }
//-------------------------------------------------
  //Open the card
  public void openCard(){     
    System.out.println("OPEN");
    //Cards are red when open
    this.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED,
      new CornerRadii(6), null)));
    this.setText("OPEN");
  }
//-------------------------------------------------
  //Close the card
  public void closeCard(){
    System.out.println("CLOSE");
    //Cards are blue when closed
    this.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.DEEPSKYBLUE,
        new CornerRadii(6), null)));
    this.setText("CLOSED");
  }
//-------------------------------------------------
  //Getters for row and column info
  public int getRow() { return row; }
  public int getColumn() { return column; }
}
```

**The main (includes the view and start point of the app)** : `Main.java`

```
package memory;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

//-------------------------------------------------  
  //The layout and the cards
  GridPane gridCard = new GridPane();
  static Card [][] cardArray;
  //The event handler
  private static EventHandler<MouseEvent> handler;
  //The array which remembers the pairs and the reminder of last open card
  static int[][] indexArray;
  static int index;
  //Boolean array to check if the card is already open
  static boolean[][] isOpen;
  //Number of pairs to find
  static int pairs = 5;
//-------------------------------------------------
  //Cheap main
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
  }
//-------------------------------------------------
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    //Init the event handler
    handler = new Controller();

    //Some formatting for the grid pane
    gridCard.setHgap(10);
    gridCard.setVgap(10);
    gridCard.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10));
    gridCard.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    //Creating our card board, index array and bool array
    cardArray = new Card [2][5];
    indexArray = new int [2][5];
    isOpen = new boolean [2][5];
    //Adding the cards to our card array
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        cardArray[i][j] = new Card(i, j);
        //Make those buttons look like cards
        cardArray[i][j].setPrefHeight(100);
        cardArray[i][j].setPrefWidth(70);
        //Register the event
        cardArray[i][j].addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, gameController());
        //Add those cards
        gridCard.add(cardArray[i][j], j, i);
        //Set the pairs (no randomness here)
        indexArray[i][j] = j+1;
      }
    }
    //Print out the indexes of all the cards
    System.out.println("----------------");
    System.out.println("Card indexes :");
    for (int i = 0; i < indexArray.length; i++) {
      System.out.println();
      for (int j = 0; j < indexArray[0].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(indexArray[i][j]+ " | ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("----------------");

    //Set BorderPane
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    root.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLACK,
        CornerRadii.EMPTY, null)));  
    root.setCenter(gridCard);   

    //Set the stage
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Memory Test");
    primaryStage.show();



  }
//-------------------------------------------------  
  //Getter for the event handler
  public static EventHandler<MouseEvent> gameController() {
    return handler;
  }
//-------------------------------------------------
  //Getter, Setter and "resetter" for the index
  public static void resetIndex() { index = 0; }
  public static int getIndex() { return index; }
  public static void setIndex(int i) {
    index = i;
  }
//-------------------------------------------------
}
```

**The controller** : `Controller.java`

```
package memory;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class Controller implements EventHandler<MouseEvent>{

//-------------------------------------------------
  @Override
  public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
    //Get the card which cas clicked on
    Card card = (Card) event.getSource();

    //If the card was already open, don't do anything
    if (!Main.isOpen[card.getRow()][card.getColumn()]) {
      //Open the card
      card.openCard();

      //We opened the first card of the turn
      if (Main.getIndex() == 0) {

        //Set the card as open
        Main.isOpen[card.getRow()][card.getColumn()] = true;
        //Remember the index
        Main.setIndex(Main.indexArray[card.getRow()][card.getColumn()]);
        System.out.println("index: "+Main.getIndex());

      //We opened the second card
      }else if (Main.getIndex() != 0) {

        //Check if it is a pair
        if (Main.getIndex() == Main.indexArray[card.getRow()][card.getColumn()]) {

          //Decrement the number of pairs
          Main.pairs--;
          //Open the second card
          Main.isOpen[card.getRow()][card.getColumn()] = true;
          //Reset the index
          Main.resetIndex();

        }else{ //Close both cards if it isn't a pair
          //Wait 0.7 second to let the player remember the cards
          try {
            Thread.sleep(700);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          //Close the current card
          card.closeCard();
          System.out.println("index : " + Main.indexArray[card.getRow()][card.getColumn()]);
          Main.isOpen[card.getRow()][card.getColumn()] = false;
          //Close the first opened card by looking at the index
          //It closes both cards with the same index, but it doesn't matter
          //as the pair hasn't been found anyway
          for (int i = 0; i < Main.indexArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Main.indexArray[0].length; j++) {
              if (Main.getIndex() == Main.indexArray[i][j]) {
                Main.cardArray[i][j].closeCard();
                System.out.println("index: " + Main.indexArray[i][j]);
                Main.isOpen[i][j] = false;
              }
            }
          }
          //Reset the index of last opened card
          Main.resetIndex();
        }
      }
    }

    //Check endgame
    if (Main.pairs == 0) {
      //Show a dialog box
      Alert incorrectPairs = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
      incorrectPairs.setTitle("GAME OVER");
      incorrectPairs.setHeaderText("The game is over");
      incorrectPairs.setContentText("You found all the pairs, congrats!");
      incorrectPairs.showAndWait();
    }
  }
//-------------------------------------------------
}
```

Comment: You probably need to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for anyone to be able to help with this. All sorts of things may be happening that can't be diagnosed from the code snippets you've posted (is `setOpenCardDesign(...)` being called first? Is the path to the image correct? etc). Create the smallest possible executable example you can that includes this code and shows the same behavior, and edit your question to include it.

Comment: Have you tried any type of debugging? Add a  print statement right after you call the openCard method. If the print statement works properly, you're logic is correct and we just need to focus on the openCard method itself.

Comment: @Haloboy yes,  I did use print statements even up to both lines right before and right after the `setGraphic() ` method call in the `openCard()` method. They get printed out but the graphic of the button-card doesn't get changed.

Comment: @James_D thank you for the advice,  I'll work on a MVCE version of the code and edit my question asap

Comment: I'll watch for it. Consider using something for the graphic that doesn't rely on an external resource (e.g. use rectangles of different colors, or something). That will make it easier for others to run and will also help you isolate the problem.

Comment: Another debug suggestion: print the `card` object both in the mouseEvent method after you initialize it to `event.getSource()` and again in the `openCard()` method and analyze if the result is any different when they're pairs versus when they're not pairs and report back please.

Comment: @Haloboy by printing the `card` object, do you mean check if the reference has changed?

Comment: yes, check reference on both ends.. or print out if each card has an identifying toString().

Comment: @James_D I have finally finished the MCVE version of my game. It reproduces the bug where the second cards never comes into the "open" state when both cards don't form a pair.

Comment: You're blocking the UI thread with `Thread.sleep(...)`. That prevents any pending changes from being repainted.

Comment: @James_D Thank you for pointing this out. I didn't learn to work with threads yet. I found a work around. I am using a timeline, assigning a duration of 500 ms to it and play it right afterwards. The only bad thing is that if you click to fast on some other cards, it may find a pair because the cards weren't closed yet. I guess it will do, I can't come with anything better. Anyway, big thank's for that. I'll let you write an answer.

Comment: A `Timeline` is a perfectly good approach here; a `PauseTransition`, which is essentially a special case of a `Timeline` is a bit easier. BTW, in the future, you should provide a MCVE as part of your question, instead of linking to it; and try to make it minimal (you could cut a lot of extraneous code out here and still show the issue you had).

Comment: @James_D Thank you for your comment and advice. When you say provide, do you mean quote the code in my question? Or directly give a jar file in the case of java?

Comment: Include the code for the full example, instead of linking to it. If the page you linked is ever removed, the question becomes meaningless for future stack overflow users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're blocking the UI thread with `Thread.sleep(...)`. That prevents any pending changes from being repainted, so you don't see the first update at all; you only see the subsequent updates after the pause is complete.

The simplest way to implement a pause on the UI thread is to use a [`PauseTransition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html) from the JavaFX animation API. Basically, you do

```
PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(700));
pause.setOnFinished(e -> {
    // code to execute after pause...
});
pause.play();
```

In your case, you probably want to disable the user interface, so the user cannot click on anything during the pause, so you could do something like

```
PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(700));
pause.setOnFinished(e -> {
    card.closeCard();

    // ... etc...

    card.getParent().setDisable(false);
});

card.getParent().setDisable(true);
pause.play();
```